# Flutter Selected Photos Permission still gives access to all photos

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

I'm using image_picker for my flutter app, When I select the limit access option from the permissions prompt all of the photos get available to select despite the permission set to limited.

[image]

I've read that this is an issue related with the PHPicker library, also that there is a related issue in github and apple with no solution:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65995

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663098

I want to know if there is a way to make it work as it should or if there's an alternative package the allows me to choose between single and multiple image pick as this one. multi_image_picker is suppose to work but it doesn't offer the option to only allow to pick one photo.

Comment: which image-picker version u using?

Comment: @Nguyenfamily I tried with 0.8.7+5 and 1.0.4